# Linq query is not executing properly

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'am trying to sum up DataTable column's in linq. But when the program is running the foreach loop is not executing. I already checked milion times if the column names are equal to datatable.

```
resultDataTable.Columns.Add("User ID");
resultDataTable.Columns.Add("Amount");
resultDataTable.Columns.Add("Order number");


var query = from row in result.AsEnumerable()
            group row by row.Field<string>("User ID") into grp                
            select new
            {
                Id = grp.Key,
                Sum = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Amount")),
                Sum2 = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Order number"))       
            };

foreach(var item in query)
{
    resultDataTable.Rows.Add(item.Id, item.Sum, item.Sum2);
}
```

The result is DataTable with 3 columns. The first one is name and last name, second one is number and third is number also.

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: Can you specify which value exactly is `null` in debugger? Is it value of some field?

Comment: Did you try with ToList()?  Like this  Select new{...}.ToList()

Comment: Do a sanity check, see if `result` has any values and if they enumerate properly.

Comment: It looks like lazy loading problem. As @AlperTungaArslan says, add a `ToList()` which will cause the query to fetch the results.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ... yeah - there is a call-stack also - so maybe Bronchi can use this to find the reason why he get no results ... anyway do you think you can help him from what we got here? Without sitting in front of the code/database and running it ... in the debugger?

Comment: When i add ToList() I get " '<anonymous type: string Id, int Sum, int Sum2>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type '<anonymous type: string Id, int Sum, int Sum2>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: you have to do this for your `query` - so either use a new line: `var list = query.ToList();` - or use `var query = (from ... }).ToList();` - but I doubt this will help you - this just forces the query just like `foreach` does anyway

Comment: to be clear: most likely your `query` does not return rows - for example because your `result` (which we don't see) does not contain *any* ... so there is probably no way we can help you from here

Comment: @Carsten right query doesnt return row you need to get values. And i think you must take like this query.ToList().

Comment: @AlperTungaArslan no the `ToList` is not necessary at all - it sometimes is if you query a context and dispose it before you use the enumeration - but in this case the very next thing is the `foreach` and this will do it anyway

Comment: @Bronchi: you still haven't answered the first comment's question of Sergey, what value is `null`? Whatis _"Current Row"_? Your title is incorrect, the query is never `null`. If the `foreach` loop isn't entered it's something completely different. That can only be if the table was empty(`result.Rows.Count==0`).

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry it was my lack of understanding(this whole null value).
But anyway, datatable result is not empty http://imageshack.com/a/img911/6131/QLlfhq.png, as I said it is filled properly. and yes the foreach loop isn't entered.(breakpoint after foreach is never hit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have created the source table in the same way as the destination table, by adding the columns manually. Then i guess that they also contained `String`-columns instead of `int` columns. Note that the default is `String`.

So following creates and adds three columns of type string:

```
resultDataTable.Columns.Add("User ID");
resultDataTable.Columns.Add("Amount");
resultDataTable.Columns.Add("Order number");
```

Instead use the overload:

```
resultDataTable.Columns.Add("User ID");
resultDataTable.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(int));
resultDataTable.Columns.Add("Order number", typeof(int));
```

Why is that important? Because you otherwise can't use `Sum = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Amount"))` since that column's type isn't `int` but `string` and you'll get a runtime `InvalidCastException` in [`Field`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx) at the `foreach`. Maybe you have an empty `try...catch` somewhere which swallows this exception and should be avoided.

A better way to create the table and the columns, if the destination table has the same columns is to use `DataTable.Clone`:

```
DataTable resultDataTable = result.Clone(); // same columns but empty
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it does't work :( (I used now .Clone()) . I create DataTable result with generic parser url: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F using the GenericParserAdapter and result = parser1.GetDataTable(); The data is from .CSV file.

Comment: @Bronchi: i still think that you don't use `int` columns in the source-table, do you? If it's generated from a parser, the parser will not know that this is an `int`-value. You have to parse it yourself and use `int.Parse` to get the `int`-value from the csv-value. Then you can sum the values. You can't sum strings. However, you will get a runtime exception at `r.Field<int>` for sure if the column is of type string.

Comment: I checked this by adding values by myself to int column in DataTable, and indeed it is the problem. Thank you for pointing this. I will try to parse data from csv by myself or to somehow change string values to int in this 2 columns.